# Conversion to normalized radar cross section of PALSAR data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, normalize, synthetic-aperture-radar

I am mapping deforestation driven by palm oil expansion in Malaysia.

I am using ALOS PALSAR data from JAXA available directly on [Google Earth Engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JAXA_ALOS_PALSAR_YEARLY_SAR). Those data are raw and I'd like to process them to better detect the plantation.

I speckle filtered the data with [a code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2e158b8ea689a0e927cfa4cdccd62def) already available. I still need to convert data to normalized radar cross section. Is there a code already available to do this normalization?